# entity framework table with optional foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

First of all, I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm trying to do a project using the Code-First model, so please forgive my ignorance on what may turn out to be a trivial problem...

I'm working on creating some POCO EF classes and I'm having difficulty figuring out how to setup some of the relationships in the `DbContext` derived class.

If I were to setup the tables with SQL, this is what they would look like (extraneous columns removed for clarity and brevity:

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.Application (
  ApplicationId NUMERIC(18,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  MinimumVersionId NUMERIC(18,0),
  CurrentVersionId NUMERIC(18,0));

CREATE TABLE DBO.ApplicationVersion (
  ApplicationVersionId NUMERIC(18,0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  ApplicationId NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE DBO.Application ADD
  PRIMARY KEY (ApplicationId),
  CONSTRAINT Application_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (MinimumVersionId)
    REFERENCES DBO.ApplicationVersion (ApplicationVersionId),
  CONSTRAINT Application_FK2
    FOREIGN KEY (CurrentVersionId)
    REFERENCES DBO.ApplicationVersion (ApplicationVersionId);
ALTER TABLE DBO.ApplicationVersion ADD
  PRIMARY KEY (ApplicationVersionId),
  CONSTRAINT ApplicationVersion_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (ApplicationId)
    REFERENCES DBO.Application (ApplicationId);
```

The relevant part of the ApplicationModel POCO class is (Application DB Table shown above):

```
public class ApplicationModel
{
    public long ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationVersionModel CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public long? CurrentVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationVersionModel MinimumVersion { get; set; }
    public long? MinimumVersionId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ApplicationVersionModel> Versions { get; set; }
}
```

And the ApplicationVersionM POCO class (ApplicationVersion DB Table shown above):

```
public class ApplicationVersionModel
{
    public virtual ApplicationModel Application { get; set; }
    public long ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public long ApplicationVersionId { get; set; }
}
```

So far, in the `OnModelCreating` method of the class that inherits from `DbContext`, I have this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationModel>()
    .HasMany<ApplicationVersionModel>(a => a.Versions)
    .WithRequired(av => av.Application)
    .HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicationId);
```

This is to establish the one to many relationship between Application and ApplicationVersion.

Where I'm getting confused is how to write the entries for the CurrentVersion and MinimumVersion fields.  Each of these are to hold a value that would be found in ApplicationVersion.ApplicationVersionId (the primary key).  However, these fields are nullable in the database and, therefore, optional.

I'm getting lost in all the options like:

`WithMany`              - I know this one isn't it as I'm pointing to a single record

`WithOptionalDependant`

`WithOptionalPrincipal`

`WithRequired`          - I don't think this is it since the field is nullable

And then, I'm not exactly sure what methods would be chained after that.

Any help would be appreciated.  It would also be beneficial if, in your answers, you could explain WHY I need to do it that way.  Knowing why will help me (and possibly others that may read the question) understand the processes and relationships better.

Comment: Just looking around Code First like you.  I had better results using `ICollection` instead of `IList`.  So far, EF created the tables (including relations) without me implementing an `OnModelCreating` event.

Comment: Yes, I meant to put `ICollection` instead of `IList`.  I'm actually using a different collection class, but changed it above to simplify the question.  I also have quite a few other tables involved with varying complexities, which is why I'm using the `OnDataModelCreating`.